# React native navigation problem in HeaderBackButton.tsx whenever I use props.navigation.navigate('Game')

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-navigation

Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: %s.%s%s, undefined,  You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

Check your code at HeaderBackButton.tsx:152.

My code is the following:

```js
const Home: FunctionComponent<HomeProps> = (props: HomeProps) => {


    return (
        <View style={styles.container}>
            <View>
                <Text>{"Listo para jugar Cuarenta ? "}</Text>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Button title="Rules" onPress={() => {
                    console.log("Props", props);
                    props.navigation.navigate('Cuarenta');

                }}/>
            </View>

            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Button title="New Game" onPress={() => {
                    props.navigation.navigate('Game');
                }}></Button>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Button title="Tablero" onPress={() => {
                    props.navigation.navigate('Tablero');
                }}></Button>
            </View>
            <View style={styles.button}>
                <Button title="Robot" onPress={() => {
                    props.navigation.navigate('RobotScene');
                }}></Button>
            </View>

        </View>
    )
}
```

```js
export default function App() {
    return (
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator
                screenOptions={{
                    headerStyle: {
                        backgroundColor: '#f41e9e',
                    },
                    headerTintColor: '#fff',
                    headerTitleStyle: {
                        fontWeight: 'bold',
                    },
                }}
            >
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='Home'
                    component={Home}
                    options={{title: 'Juego de Cuarenta'}}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='Cuarenta'
                    component={Cuarenta}

                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='Game'
                    component={GameScene}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='Tablero'
                    component={Tablero}
                />
                <Stack.Screen
                    name='RobotScene'
                    component={RobotScene}
                />

            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    );
}
```

Comment: Can you add the code of `GameScene` component please?

Comment: Well this happens for every component , idk what I did or install, but everything whent wrong since yesterday night.

Comment: Okay so one thing , this happened after I updated expo.

Comment: I roll back to the previous commit and everything is up and running, although this is a pretty weird case ( ._. )

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solve this by rolling back to expo 38.0.8(the original version of my project).

Answer (score 0):

I ran into the same problem updating `react-navigation`:

```
@react-navigation/native  ^5.7.2  →  ^5.7.3
@react-navigation/stack   ^5.8.0  →  ^5.9.0
```

Reverting back fixes the problem for now.

Answer (score 0):

In my case the new version (5.7.2+?) of @react-navigation/stack was the reason. So just run npm i @react-navigation/stack@5.7.1 for fix it